# How to solve the problem :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: promisify is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, typeerror, node-promisify

Below is my code.
I use node v12.16.3 and npm v6.14.4.

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json');
```

And the console showed error like this:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: promisify is not a function`

Where I call promisify:

```
async function accessSpreadsheet(){
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(MY_GOOGLESHEET_ADDRESS);
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
    const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset:1
    });
    rows.forEach(row =>{
        if(row.userid=='dog'){
            var num = parseInt(row.point,10);
            num+=1;
            row.point = num;
            row.save();
        }
    })
}
```

What should I do to solve the error?

New for nodejs ,I will be willing to know and learn anything.Thanks!

Comment: I believe you use a wrong version of node. Promisify is a relatively new feature.

Comment: Share the code where the error is happening. Is it in the import itself ? When you call promisify, there it might be wrong usage.

Answer (score -1):

You should use promisify variable without { }

```
const promisify = require('util');
```

or

```
const util = require('util');
util.promisify(some code);
```

Comment: I tried both way but it still didn't work.And it showed the same error.